# How to modify prop and set it to initial state in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I get a prop `text`, which is string. I need to trim this text and pass it to component state. How to do this? In the old way I could use `componentDidMount` function. Now I try with `useEffect()` hook but it doesn't work. "Cannot read property 'substring' of null". What am I doing wrong?

```
export const ReadMore: React.FC<IReadMoreProps> = ({
 text, characterLimit,
}) => {

const [textValue, trimText] = useState(text);

useEffect(() => {
  trimText(text.substring(0, characterLimit));
});

return (
  <>
   {textValue}
  </>
 );
};
```

Comment: looks like your text prop is null.

Comment: try logging your text

Comment: It's not null. When I remove substring method everything render properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is outside the code you shared. (see sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-fire-e3w4w)

*text* prop must be null when the component is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need state in this case. You can do something like this.

```
export const ReadMore: React.FC<IReadMoreProps> = ({
 text, characterLimit,
}) => {
const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
const textValue = showMore ? text : (text || "").substring(0, characterLimit);
return (
  <>
   {textValue}
  </>
 );
};
```

Comment: But I wish add "read more", "read less" feature, so I need to manipulate of my state I guess.

Comment: you can have that state and calculate text based on that value.  updated my answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that may be a type issue. Try this:

```
export const ReadMore: React.FC<IReadMoreProps> = ({
 text, characterLimit,
}) => {

const [textValue, trimText] = useState(text);

useEffect(() => {
  trimText(text.toString().substring(0, characterLimit));
}, [text]);

return (
  <>
   {textValue}
  </>
 );
};
```

Hope this works for you.